# Por que no me muestra el JLabel correctamente?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy creando una ventana con menu e items, entre uno de esos items al seleccionarlo le pido al codigo que coloque un JLabel y un JTextField.

El problema es que al primer intento el JLabel sale cortado.

```
public class Ventana implements ActionListener {

JFrame ventana2;
JLabel Label1;
JTextField EntradaV;

public void CrearMenu(){
Label1 = new JLabel();
EntradaV = New JTexTField();
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent A){
  if (A.getSource() == Op1){
    Label1.setText("Ingrese el numero del mes.");
    Dimension sizeLabel = Label1.getPreferredSize();
    Label1.setBounds(1,80, sizeLabel.width, sizeLabel.height);

    Dimension sizeText = EntradaV.getPreferredSize();
    EntradaV.setBounds(1,100, sizeText.width, sizeText.height);

    ventana2.add(Label1);
    ventana2.add(EntradaV);
  }
```

Esto es lo que me muestra de salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Soy nuevo en la programación y apenas empece a ver swing

Answer (score 0):

Haz que el JLabel tenga mas espacio dentro del panel, asígnale "más" borde.

Cuando haces:
`Label1.setBounds(1,80, sizeLabel.width, sizeLabel.height);`

juega con el width, por ejemplo:

`Label1.setBounds(1,80, sizeLabel.width+50, sizeLabel.height);`

y así hasta que el tamaña del texto aparezca correctamente.